# MySQL get most recent entries from a big table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with more than 50k entries and a few users:

```
transactions Table:
ID
USER
VALUE
TIMESTAMP

users Table:
USER
TYPE
REGION
```

I would like to get the most recent transactions for each user. So far I am using the following GROUP BY statement, but it is slow (takes 5-10sec approx):

```
select ID , max(TIMESTAMP) as TIMESTAMP from transactions group by USER;
```

Is there a faster statement to retrieve the most recent entries?

Comment: you want only latest TIMESTAMP? or full record?

Comment: As Zafar comments, my proposed group by is wrong, the proper statement would be: GROUP BY USER

Comment: Please try my solution once.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the statement you are using, there must be something else affecting the speed of the query for it to take 5-10 seconds. I created a table and filled it with 500,000 rows  and on first execution, without additional indexes, it returned the results of your query in 2 seconds. Can you post the full `CREATE TABLE` SQL and an execution plan of that query? That may give some other clues as to the problem.

Comment: @Tony, USER is TEXT type and is not under my control. And the machine running the DB server is an embedded system, and it is not very powerful. Having better hardware would also help. Moreover, the actual table has more fields that I must return, I simplified it to make it more clear. I guess all together reduces the speed.

Comment: @guiz - Ahh.. embedded system, that'll be it ;) Fair enough, I thought you were using a "desktop" install of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as per my understanding ID columns should keep unique values in transaction table so group by should be on USER field as per your requirement.

Further you can try below query. I am not sure but you can compare its time with your query and use accordingly.

```
SELECT 
USER , TIMESTAMP 
FROM
 (SELECT USER,TIMESTAMP FROM transactions ORDER BY ID DESC) a 
GROUP BY USER;
```

Assuming there will be an index on USER column as this is common between both tables.

Comment: Thank you, @ZafarMalik. I mistyped the original query, as you mention it should have been "group by USER". In the other hand I think you forgot to add max(TIMESTAMP). Do you mean to index USER column in TRANSACTIONS table? Shouldn't it be unique in order to index it? I cannot see the advantage of your query, it first sorts all the table and then applies GROUP BY. I tried it and it gives zero results.

Comment: There is no need of max(timestamp) as doing group by which will provide only first row after getting it descending order means latest row only. Your query is slow due to this max function. My query can give better results if USER columns will be indexed.

Comment: Hi @ZafarMalik. Previously I mistyped your solution. I tried it again and your it works properly and faster than the original one. From 5.10sec goes down to 3.40sec. I created an index by executing CREATE INDEX USER_ID ON TRANSACTIONS (USER(9)); but it did not speed up the query.

Comment: You can get performance after a little bit change in schema, add a user_id column (int type) in user against each user which cane primary key for user table and keep user_id instead of user in transaction table. Now you will do group by based on user_id instead of user in your query which will be fast.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify TRANSACTIONS table, it is fed by a software that is not under my control. Moreover, USER is TEXT type even storing a 9 digit number. In the other hand I can modify USERS table. Would it be of any use?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
select u.*,tr.* from users  as u
outer apply
    (
    select top 1 * from transactions as t
      where t.USER= u.USER
      order by t.ID desc
)as tr
```

Comment: your code is specific for SQL-server. The question is about a MySQL. Instead of top you could use `limit 1`.

Comment: Thank you @AK47. MySQL Workbench finds an error on this SQL. It underlines the word "outer" indicating there is a problem there.

Comment: ya, Code which I have given is of SQL Server.

Comment: That is why `outer` gives a problem.

Comment: try by replacing outer by cross.

Comment: @AK47, "apply" is not recognized by the parser